# How can I write SQL if I have search by date

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I want to search `From Date` and `To Date`. This is a two field search. When I type the date in field `From Date` and leave field `To Date` empty, I must receive the result between `From Date` and `Date Now`. But when I write `To Date` and leave the field `From Date` empty, I must receive all records until the written date (which written in field `To Date`).

How can I write correct SQL for this?
I wrote this so far:

```
`WHERE (@FromDate is null or CN.[FromDate] between Cast(@FromDate as date) AND Cast(@ToDate as date))`
```

Nothing is happening currently, however.

Comment: You have to handle missing values either at the c# level or the database level.  I suggest the c# level.  Start by writing in English what you want to do, then convert those sentences to programming code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `between`.  Instead, split the comparison into two pieces:

```
WHERE (@FromDate is null or CN.FromDate >= Cast(@FromDate as date)) AND
      (@ToDate is null or CN.FromDate <= Cast(@ToDate as date));
```

If `@FromDate` and `@ToDate` are declared as `date`, then the `cast()` is  not necessary.

EDIT:

If you have an index on `FromDate` and your dates are within reasonable values, the following is more "sargable":

```
WHERE CN.FromDate >= coalesce(@FromDate, '1950-01-01') and
      CN.ToDate < coalesce(@ToDate, '2100-01-01')
```

EDIT II:

Comparison operations on dates can be dangerous, because dates might sometimes have time components (if your variable is really a `datetime`.  That means that a safer way of writing the original code is:

```
WHERE (@FromDate is null or CN.FromDate >= Cast(@FromDate as date)) AND
      (@ToDate is null or CN.FromDate < dateadd(day, 1, Cast(@ToDate as date)));
```

This means that it will work intuitively even when `FromDate` is a `datetime` with a time component.

All the operations are on constants, so SQL Server can use an index on the column.

Comment: I always prefer and less than the day after the end date.

Comment: @DanBracuk . . . I do agree, although I'm not religious about this issue when the fields are explicitly set to dates.  Because it is a good idea, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using COALESCE to write everything on a single line:

```
WHERE CN.FromDate >= COALESCE(@FromDate, CN.FromDate) AND CN.ToDate <= COALESCE(@ToDate, CN.ToDate)
```